# What does CustomProperty.bin in Office Open XML format stand for?

Tags: xml, excel, openxml

I have a *.xlsx format file made by Excel, and I know this kind of format is a compressed file exactly. So I opened this with 7-Zip and found out there is a lot of xml files and a binary file which name is CustomPropert1.bin. What's this? How can I have a new file made by myself with it? I have googled a lot, but nothing helped. Does andbody know it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

.bin files contains the definition of the file format itself. So here, the CustomPropert1.bin describe the file format of customProperty.

Like that my explaination is a little bit dark, but a whole article talk about it here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15216/Office-bin-file-format

Comment: Thank you.But I want to made a new file with customProperty.bin by myself, and I knew nothing about customProperty. What will cause a xlsx file contain it?

Comment: You have to create customProperty with the open xml sdk, and the bin file will be created by it.
If you read the link in the response, it show what the bin file contain once you add custom Property (look at the "workbook part"). So create your custom properties, and don't the bin file